# Automatically re-size div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to automatically resize div according the background-image size.

Is that possible with css?

I also need to update the background-image using jquery.

Until now I have: [Resize div](http://jsfiddle.net/77hGW/)

Updated: JSFiddle link: [Updated Link](http://jsfiddle.net/77hGW/1/) Is it easier to place the `hand` above the image element instead of setting a background-image for the div?

Comment: Does it need to be `background-image`, or would you be willing to use an `<img>` tag?

Comment: I have already implemented it with <img> tag and its working but I need it to be a <div> because I need to `hand` element to be over the image

Comment: I will move the hand using jquery draggable..

Comment: Even with the update I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With css no there is no way to currently do this at the moment you can do it with javascript as shown below.

To set a background image

```
$("#yourdiv").css("background-image", "your url");
```

To get background image height or width is a real pain something like this should work

```
$.fn.getBgImage = function(callback) {
    var height = 0;
    var path = $(this).css('background-image').replace('url', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
    var tempImg = $('<img />');
    tempImg.hide(); //hide image
    tempImg.bind('load', callback);
    $('body').append(tempImg); // add to DOM before </body>
    tempImg.attr('src', path);
    $('#tempImg').remove(); //remove from DOM
};


// usage
$("#background").getBgImage(function() {
    console.log($(this).height());
});
```

Comment: This is a lot easier in regular javascript.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible with css but if you are replacing the background image with jQuery, it's easy to resize the div with javascript at the same moment.

Example:

```
var url = "some_url_to_image", image_width, image_height;
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  image_width = this.width;
  image_height = this.height;
}
image.src = url;
```

If you want to position an element on top of another element, you can use absolute positioning.